# How to access a derived class field from a base class array?

Tags: c#, arrays, derived-class

I looked through similar threads and they all pertain to C++, so I assume it's better to ask than to just fumble around. I have, for example, this code:

```
foo[] fooArray = new foo[5];
fooArray[2] = new bar();
```

Say that `foo` is a custom class with no variables/methods:

```
public class foo
{

}
```

and that `bar` is a custom class derived from `foo`:

```
public class bar : foo
{
    int fooBar = 0;
}
```

In my `fooArray`, I need to access the variable `fooBar` from `fooArray[2]`, which is a `bar`, but as the variable doesn't appear in the base class, it doesn't show up in an array of `foo`s. Is there any way I can access it?

Edit: In the application code, both foo and bar have the required constructors and other settings.

Comment: You can't. However, you can promote the field to base-class-status..

Comment: I think you need to revise your design. What if you have dozens of derived classes, each with their own properties...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast one of the items in the array to `bar` and as access it that way,

```
bar barVar = (bar)fooArray[2];
int fooBarInt = barVar.fooBar;
```

Or use the `as` operator to treat the object as type `bar`,

```
bar barVar = fooArray[2] as bar;
if (barVar != null)
{
    // user barVar.fooBar;
}
```

However, the way it is define in your example `fooBar` is `private`. You would have to make it `public` to access it outside of the class.

```
public class bar : foo
{
    public int fooBar = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your solution worked perfectly. Also, fooBar was public in my application code, just forgot to type it in :)

Answer (score 1):

You could cast. In order to be safe you should use the `as` keyword:

```
bar b = fooArray[2] as bar
if ( b != null ){
   //Do stuff with b.foobar
} else {
   //Handle the case where it wasn't actually a bar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `foo` class don't have `fooBar` field.You can't access it unless you cast your  variable to `Bar`:

```
fooArray[2] = new bar();
var value = ((bar)fooArray[2]).fooBar;
```

Note: `fooBar` field should be **public**.Fields are **private** by default.

Comment: There is something **very very very** wrong with your design if you need to do this.

Comment: I don't get that Simon :D Could you please more clear ? in this case he should cast it but ofcorse using an intercafe would better.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Your comment really belongs on the OP itself.

Comment: If you are storing a list of derived types in a list of base types... then casting them back every time you need to access them.. whats the point of the base list in the first place? They are pointless casts. @rae1 This is a comment to the OP really. If this is the "solution" to the OP's problem.. then the OP needs to rethink their design. The code becomes messy very quickly doing this. You'll end up casting to the wrong type at some point too.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I agree with you but I just answered the OP's question.

Comment: @Selman22 I know.. my comments are for the OP. I put them on your answer so the OP see's it when they look at the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access it you would need to cast the value to a `bar` instance

```
int i = ((bar)fooArray[2]).foobar;
```

Note that if `fooArray[2]` isn't actually an instance of `bar` this code will throw an exception.  If you want to do this only if `fooArray[2]` is a `bar` then do the following

```
bar b = fooArray[2] as bar;
if (b != null) {
  int i = b.foobar;
  ...
}
```